# What happens to my reputation if op deletes his question?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Let say I give an answer to a post and my answer is accepted and upvoted. What happens to my reputation if the op deletes his post? Will I lose my reputation that I gain from it?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: quite sure the Asker can't delete their question if there is 1 upvoted answer, only a Mod can delete it then, not sure about just an upvote though

Comment: @Memor-X it can be deleted by the community if the question got closed and have at least -3, so this is a common situation

Comment: Then don't answer bad questions.

Comment: Also see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) on [meta.se], section "If you posted a question that you regret posting", also search for "Exception" on that page.

Comment: Even though the question itself isn't asking the general "why did I gain/lose reputation" question, the duplicate still applies because it thoroughly explains what happens when a question is deleted where you have answered.

Comment: A bit of advice: try to not call it reputation *loss*. It is a correction of the bookkeeping, nothing more. Its best to learn early that reputation is not something you own.

Comment: No-rep users have enormous power, only a mod is as powerful to delete your post with a single vote.  But an upvote or answer mark on your post stops him, he can no longer delete the question.